# How to make GroudControl AppearanceCaption transparent

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I just upgraded my Deexpress from 16.2 to 23.1.
I'm having problems with GroudControl's BorderColor.
With version 16.2, the Caption section has no surrounding color.
but after upgrading to 23.1, there is border color around.

[image]

I have tried
Me.GroupControl1.AppearanceCaption.BorderColor = Color.Transparent
but it still has border color in the Caption section

Comment: If you add a new one to form, does it render correctly?

Comment: Hi Shahram,
I tried adding a new form but it still displays as shown above with devexpress 23.1 (with border color around)

Comment: Hi Hung, I was not able to reproduce the problem in any way. Actually, there is no control over caption text background unless the skins are disabled and the `Group Style` is set to `Light`. I think there is a property from the old version that is now obsolete in version 23. Can you post the designer code of the group control (from the designer.vb)?